# Placeholder syntax for Node mysql "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" clause with multiple rows and columns update

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am struggling to find the correct syntax when using placeholders with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause when multiple rows and columns need to be updated.

For instance: Here is how I am doing a simple Insert command for multiple rows. How would I change it to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

```
let twoDimensionArray = [keycol, colA, colB, colC, colD]
// iterate to add more rows.

let fullQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (keycol, colA, colB, colC, colD) VALUES ?"

con.query(fullQuery,[twoDimensionArray], function(err, result) {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: [MySQL Reference Manual :: VALUES() Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)

Comment: @akina thanks. But how do you do this using a placeholder ?

Comment: Placeholders needed in VALUES clause only. ODKU clause have no placeholders.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that ODKU clauses cannot have placeholders? If this is true, does this mean that I cannot convert the above statement as an UPDATE .. ODKU, instead of an INSERT statement?

Comment: I have said that **IN THIS CASE** the ODKU clause do not need in placeholders because the VALUES() function exists.

Answer (score 0):

(The MySQL side; still need the node.js to weigh in)

Adapted from the first example in the mysql docs:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b)
```

You would need

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

unless node.js provides some way to have on placeholder represent a list of values  or a list of a list.

Comment: Thanks Rick. As you point out, the whole idea is to have placeholder so I don't have to explicitly name each field. While this is an example, my real life use case deals with 70+ fields. It seems odd that Placeholder feature does not support  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clauses

Comment: @ChrisF - So, it seems that this boils down to a feature deficiency in NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will pursue that route